# Using a conditional statement to send to different receiver actors

Tags: scala, akka

I am new to akka and could use a little help on figuring this out, also please forgive me if I call something by the wrong name.  I have a json document that needs to go to one of two receivers based on whether or not a specific field is true.  I have been able to publish to various single consumers using:

```
Source(publisher).map{cmd =>
  println("****************** Pick up message"+cmd)
  val cmdAst = cmd.toString.parseJson
  cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded]
}.runWith(Sink.actorSubscriber(ProcessorActor.props))
```

I have tried inserting a conditional statement like this:

```
var actorSubscriber = ProcessorActor.props

Source(publisher).map { cmd =>
  println("****************** Pick up message" + cmd)
  val cmdAst = cmd.toString.parseJson
  cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded]
    if (cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded].toLocation.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Main")) {
      actorSubscriber = EventActor.props
    } else actorSubscriber = ProcessorActor.props
}.runWith(Sink.actorSubscriber(actorSubscriber))
```

Everything compiles and runs without errors, but when a form is submitted it never picks up and simply times out.

I have also tried to directly sink the subscriber the following way to the same result:

```
Source(publisher).map { cmd =>
  println("****************** Pick up message" + cmd)
  val cmdAst = cmd.toString.parseJson
  cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded]
    if (cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded].toLocation.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Main")) {
      (Sink.actorSubscriber(EventActor.props)
    } else (Sink.actorSubscriber(ProcessorActor.props)}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with a [`Graph`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/stream-graphs.html) using a `Broadcast` and two distinct Sinks.  Here is an example using a `Source` of integers and splitting them to two different Sinks, one for evens and one for odds.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Sink, Flow, FlowGraph, Broadcast, Merge}
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object TwoSinks extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  FlowGraph.closed() { implicit builder: FlowGraph.Builder[Unit] =>
    import FlowGraph.Implicits._

    val source = Source(1 to 10)

    //beam splitter
    val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

    def isEven(i : Int) = i % 2 == 0

    val evenFilter = Flow[Int].filter(isEven)
    val oddFilter  = Flow[Int].filter(!isEven(_))

    val evenSink = Sink.foreach[Int](i => println(s"evenSink received : $i"))    
    val oddSink  = Sink.foreach[Int](i => println(s" oddSink received : $i"))

    source ~> bcast ~> evenFilter ~> evenSink
              bcast ~> oddFilter  ~> oddSink
  }.run()

  import actorSystem.dispatcher
  actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds){actorSystem.shutdown()}
}//end object TwoSinks
```

You can easily extend this example to use a [`Sink.actorSubscriber`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/?_ga=1.122802763.1917589872.1429296441#akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$) which use Actors within your Sinks instead of println.  Using your specific code:

```
FlowGraph.closed() {implicit builder: FlowGraph.Builder[Unit] =>
  import FlowGraph.Implicits._

  def pickupMsg(cmd : String) = 
    {println(s"****************** Pick up message: $cmd") ; cmd}

  //I don't know the type of cmdAst so I'm using "CmdAstType"
  type CmdAstType = ???

  def convert(cmd : String) : CmdAstType = {
    val cmdAst = cmd.toString.parseJson
    cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded]
    cmdAst
  }//end def convert

  val source = Source(publisher).map(pickupMsg).map(convert)

  def isEvent(cmdAst : CmdAstType) : Boolean = cmdAst.convertTo[FormAdded]
                                                     .toLocation 
                                                     .toString()
                                                     .equalsIgnoreCase("Main")

  val eventFilter     = Flow[CmdAstType].filter(isEvent)
  val processorFilter = Flow[CmdAstType].filter(!isEvent(_))

  val eventSink     = Sink.actorSubscriber[CmdAstType](EventActor.props)
  val processorSink = Sink.actorSubscriber[CmdAstType](ProcessorActor.props)

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[CmdAstType](2))

  source ~> bcast ~> eventFilter     ~> eventSink
            bcast ~> processorFilter ~> processorSink

}//end FlowGraph.closed()
```

Comment: This has a slight drawback: the condition has to be evaluated in both (or however many you have) filters, which can be a problem if it's expensive. However, this can be worked around: use `Flow.map(x => (x, condition(x))` before the `Broadcast` and combine `filter` with another `map` between the `Broadcast` and the `Sink`s.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I completely agree, but I think the `Flow.map` solution would have slightly obfuscated the general structure I was trying to explain in the answer.  As always, the devil is in the detail...

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much for your assistance.  I have applied @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil 's example, and am seeing the it get to the println statement `****************** Pick up message: {<"cmd": "JSON content">}` but it stalls out there.  The next line I get is:
  
`[DEBUG] [11/13/2015 09:34:08.617] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://default/user/$a/flow-3-4-publisherSource-prefixAndTail] Cancelling akka.stream.impl.MultiStreamOutputProcessor$SubstreamOutput@155cd6c6 (after: 5000 ms)`  
  
Do I need to change something on the receiver side?

Comment: Some care has to be taken when writing your Sink Actors.  They have to pass on demand or use a strategy.  Try using a basic println Sink first to see if that is the problem...

Comment: Read the docs to see a proper description of setting up the subscriber: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-integrations.html#ActorSubscriber

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the Sink depend on the element: the flow already exists and contains fixed `Source` and `Sink` before it runs and begins to get elements from the source (there are [ways to fan-out and have multiple sinks](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/stream-graphs.html) but none of them do what you want).

What you *can* do is have one `Sink` which will forward the elements it receives to different actors depending on the element. E.g. you can write a `DispatchActor` which looks at the messages it receives and sends them either to `EventActor` or `ProcessorActor`, and use it with `Sink.actorSubscriber(DispatchActor.props)`.

Comment: Could you expand on the `Sink` dealing with messages in the desired way?  Is there a good reference section in the akka documentation to look at, or an example of `Sink` performing the action of writing a new actor?

Comment: I didn't mean `Sink` writing a new actor, but that you can write a new actor and use it in a `Sink`.

Comment: Would the `Balance[T]` fan out not work for this situation?

Comment: No; the stream it sends an element to doesn't depend on the element itself, it just tries to balance the load between its subscribers.